# Where is the detailed parameter description of SharedTreeNode in h2o-genmodel?

Tags: h2o

I am using h2o-genmodel to parse Mojo model.

But I'm somewhat confused about some of the parameters in the generated shareTreeNode CLASS. I queried the API documentation(http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/index.html) and source code, there is no text description of any parameters.

I really need the explain of all parameters, because I need to change it to my parameters defined in my project as another format.

Here is the parameters in SharedTreeNode, some parameters like `colName` I can understand by myself. But parameters like `inclusiveNa` I am really don't know.

```
public class SharedTreeNode {
    final SharedTreeNode parent;
    final int subgraphNumber;
    int nodeNumber;
    float weight;
    final int depth;
    int colId;
    String colName;
    boolean leftward;
    boolean naVsRest;
    float splitValue = 0.0F / 0.0;
    String[] domainValues;
    GenmodelBitSet bs;
    float predValue = 0.0F / 0.0;
    float squaredError = 0.0F / 0.0;
    SharedTreeNode leftChild;
    public SharedTreeNode rightChild;
    private boolean inclusiveNa;
    private BitSet inclusiveLevels;
}
```

Here is my code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

inclusiveNa and inclusiveLevels are for calculating the tree visualization.  the arcs from parent to child node show where the NA value travels and where the different levels for a categorical split travel.

Comment: what's the meaning of NA value?

Comment: NA means not available, or a missing value.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way, if there any document of these param? params like leftward，naVsRest，inclusiveNa，inclusiveLevels， I still don't know.